# Max Payne theme scale

Tags: scales, harmony

There is something weird about the [Max Payne theme](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cv0y0On8ZGQ) in that although technically it's in C minor, it's using B-natural prominently. What is this called, where is it coming from?

Comment: I didn't listen to all of it but in the beginning the harmony sounds like standard dominant V (without 7). The melody seems to be switching between natural and harmonic C minor scales (or perhaps some kind of dominant G scale; not so familiar with those).

Answer (score 3):

It is called C **harmonic** minor scale. It was conceived to give the "leading tone" characteristic of the seventh/octave degree transition (note that B to C gives us a half-tone), and to recover the tritone on the dominant chord -- in Gm7 (G-Bb-D-F) there is no tritone, while in G7 (G-B-D-F) we have the tritone between B and F.

The tritone is a pivotal sonority when it comes into tonal harmony, as it states clearly the cadential movement one should expect of a tonal progression.

Of course, over the time composers have gained more and more freedom to subvert such rules; nonetheless, when it comes to the strict theoretical question you asked, we should still remember those old rules of thumb.

P.S.: I should add that there is also the **melodic** minor scale, which in its own namesake adds melodic cohesion, "undropping" the sixth degree as well as the seventh. In C minor, the final tetrachord would be "G-A-B-C", as opposed to "G-Ab-Bb-C" of the **natural** minor scale and "G-Ab-B-C" of the **harmonic** one. The melodical effect is related to avoiding the augmented-second leap that results from Ab-B, recovering the neighboring tones progression.

Comment: As above, the tune also has a Bb.This takes it out of the harmonic and into the melodic minor.

Comment: @Tim: actually the Bb brings it to the *natural* (aka *primitive*) minor scale. The *melodic* one also occurs briefly when the note A natural is played (please refer to my "P.S." above for further understanding). This piece effectively alternates between all three forms of the minor scale.

Answer (score 2):

Like many pieces of classical music, this theme features the **movable scale degrees** 6 and 7 of the minor mode, which can be either major or minor without leaving the key. What makes this theme especially freaky is that, instead of using B-natural in ascending motion toward the tonic (as is typical for melodic minor), this melody repeatedly employs unusual downward leaps, specifically the **diminished fourth** Eb-B and the **augmented second** B-Ab. (These intervals sound like thirds but do not function as thirds in the established key, unless we call the B a Cb, implying an even weirder sort of chromaticism.) In fact, the normal stepwise ascent A-B-C does not occur until the big cadence at 1:10.

Answer (score 0):

It's called C melodic minor. The older version of this uses C major notes on the way up, but with a flat 3 to get minor tonality. On the way down, it uses C natural minor notes, as from Eb major.

So C melodic minor contains C, D, Eb, F, G,Ab, A, Bb, B.

However, I recall a discussion elsewhere on this site about whether a key and a scale are the same.So I guess the proper answer is that it's in "C MINOR".

Melodic ascending -  C D Eb F G A B

Melodic descending - C Bb Ab G F Eb D

Harmonic -           C D Eb F G Ab B

Natural -            C D Eb F G Ab Bb  (same as melodic desc.)

Dorian -             C D Eb F G A Bb

The  unedited original answer was rubbish, but why didn't the downvoters point out the errors, or edit it themselves ? Moral - proof read before pressing 'go',

Comment: The OP wasn't clear, but assuming **only** B-natural shows up, implying Ab is in the scale, then it's harmonic minor, not melodic.